# T-test and tree don't match logically

Tags: r, t-test, cart

I would like some help in a machine learning homework.
First I want to make clear that I don't think this is considered cheating as I am just asking for help in understanding a result, rather than asking for the code/answer. After all the professor told us himself that he encourages to seek outside help when needed.

Regarding my question, I am using the `DoctorVisits` dataset from the `AER` package. Before making a tree I did some descriptive statistics on the data, including t-tests. After that I chose the column `lchronic` to make a [tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CH07O.png).

Thing is that the tree uses the variables `illness` and `age`, while the t-tests :

```
t.test(illness~lchronic, data = DoctorVisits)
t.test(age~lchronic, data = DoctorVisits)
```

both resulted in the acceptance of the null hypotheses. Therefore, seeing as the means aren't different for these variables regardless of `lchronic`, shouldn't that mean that the tree can't have them as branches?

Also, another minor thing, the branch `freerepat` seems to be doing nothing as it results to two 'No' nodes regardless of the value of `freerepat`.

Comment: When I've run the tests you indicated, I'm seeing a rejection of the null in both cases. Either way, you're asking two different questions with a CART analysis and a t-test. A CART will always look for a way to segment cases. Also, don't make the mistake of thinking that there is no difference because the p-value is greater than an arbitrary threshold.

Comment: First off, you never accept the null hypothesis.  You can only reject or fail to reject.  Second, I see a rejection of the null in both cases.  Are you using an altered dataset?

Comment: I am sorry, I was confused, the null hypothesis was rejected indeed. My problem now is understanding why the tree has a branch that ends up to the same leave twice. It doesn't make much sense, the tree that doesn't have the freerepat:no branch should be equivalent to the original.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it asks about something that does not happen.